# Can i add multiple docks?

Tags: settings, plank, apps

Can I add multiple docks?

I managed to once, by pressing the `fn` key and something else (sadly, I cannot remember.)
One dock was purple and the other was white. the purple was on the right and the white was on the left.

(it may have been `fn` + `right click` on the dock.)(also, it may not have been the `fn` key, but `command` or `alt`)

I'm not looking to mimic that, but any method that allows me to have multiple docks with separate apps on them.

Comment: i found this page but i haven't gotten to try it yet:
https://heathpaddock.com/2014/08/25/dual-docks-in-elementary-os/

Comment: A more simple way: https://eos-techs.com/2020/05/14/howto-run-multiply-planks-in-elementary-os/

Comment: Thanks! the one i mentioned appears to not work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i̶ ̶f̶o̶u̶n̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶p̶a̶g̶e̶ ̶b̶u̶t̶ ̶i̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶g̶o̶t̶t̶e̶n̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶t̶r̶y̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶y̶e̶t̶:̶ ̶h̶e̶a̶t̶h̶p̶a̶d̶d̶o̶c̶k̶.̶c̶o̶m̶/̶2̶0̶1̶4̶/̶0̶8̶/̶2̶5̶/̶d̶u̶a̶l̶-̶d̶o̶c̶k̶s̶-̶i̶n̶-̶e̶l̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶a̶r̶y̶-̶o̶s̶
>
> > A more simple way: https://eos-techs.com/2020/05/14/howto-run-multiply-planks-in-elementary-os/

The method mentioned by @Storm appears to work well.
it does add a few seconds to startup time though.